# Haskell lazyness, evaluation order and pattern matching

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I start by saying that I'm learning Haskel so don't be too harsh.

Haskell's lazy evaluation may be useful or dangerous depending on whether a computation's bottleneck is the time complexity or the size of the stack.

For this reason I would like to understand better how evaluation works in Haskell. Let me propose an example. Consider this simple function

```
isBig :: Int -> Bool
isBig = (<=) 5
```

With this, let us define the function

```
anyBig :: [Int] -> Bool
anyBig = or . map isBig
```

Due to lazy evaluation, I would expect that `[7,1,2,1]` will evaluate to `True` by calling `isBig` only once. Let's see the evaluation order that `GHC` might do to figure this out

```
anyBig [7,1,2,1]                                    -- start
(or . map isBig) [7,1,2,1]                          -- definition of anyBig
or $ map isBig [7,1,2,1]                            -- definition of composition
foldr (||) False $ isBig 7 : map isBig [1,2,1]      -- or and map evaluated in some order
False || foldr (||) (isBig 7) (map isBig [1,2,1])   -- definition of foldr
foldr (||) (isBig 7) (map isBig [1,2,1])            -- definition of ||
```

Now at this point there are a few possibilities

1. GHC is smart enough to figure out that the only thing preventing a pattern matching is the last argument so it does

```
foldr (||) (isBig 7) (isBig 1 : map isBig [2,1])     -- definition of map
(isBig 7) || foldr (||) (isBig 1) (map isBig [2,1])  -- definition of foldr
```

2. GHC evaluates everything at the same level since there are no matches

```
foldr (||) True (isBig 1 : map isBig [2,1])          -- definition of map
True || foldr (||) (isBig 1) (map isBig [2,1])       -- definition of foldr
```

Now in case 2., by the definition of `||` the computation stops with `True`. In case 1. it is unclear to me if GHC would prefer to unwrap the `map` to get to

```
(isBig 7) || (isBig 1) || (isBig 2) || (isBig 1)
```

or if it evaluates `isBig 7` first and return as in 2. Also, suppose we truly ended up with that

```
(isBig 7) || (isBig 1) || (isBig 2) || (isBig 1)
```

that would actually be maximally show because `||` is `infixr` so it starts from the right.

Comment: It's case 1. What you then need to know is that `||` will demand the first argument, and if that is true will not demand the second one but immediately return true.

Comment: BTW, there's a mistake in your computation: after `foldr (||) False $ isBig 7 : map isBig [1,2,1]` you do not get `False || foldr (||) (isBig 7) (map isBig [1,2,1])` -- the definition of `foldr` will use `False` only when the list is empty. The correct next step is `isBig 7 || foldr (||) False (map isBig [1,2,1])`.

Comment: @chi Also, am I correct in saying that if `||` was defined by pattern matching the second entry then they would have made it `infixl` to not end up in case 2.?

Comment: The `infix` is actually irrelevant: that only affects parsing of `a || b || c`, but in your case it appears in the code as `foldr False (||)` so no fixity is used to parse `(||)`. Note that `foldr f a (x:xs)` is always equal to `f x (foldr f a xs)`, so for a long list we end up with `f x1 (f x2 (f x3 ... (f xN a)))` and the fixity won't change that. Case 2 is impossible by definition of `foldr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `(||)` function [is implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.9.0/docs/src/GHC.Classes.html#%7C%7C):

> ```
> (||)                    :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
> True  || _              =  True
> False || x              =  x
> ```

This means that it looks at the first operand, and if it is `True`, it does not pattern matching on the second one, and thus will never evaluate the rest. Only in case the first one is `False`, it will return the second operand, and this will thus continue evaluation.

This thus means that:

```
    foldr (||) False (map isBig [7,1,2,1])
 -> foldr (||) False (isBig 7 : map isBig [1,2,1])
 -> isBig 7 || (foldr (||) False (map isBig [1,2,1]))
 -> True || (foldr (||) False (map isBig [1,2,1]))
 -> True
```

If `foldr` thus uses a function that can (sometimes) return a result by only evaluating the first operand, it can thus stop recursion.

We can see this when we would pass an infinite list. Indeed, for example:

```
anyBig (1 : 7 : repeat 1)
```

Here the list is `[1, 7, 1, 1, 1, …]`, so an infinite amount of elements. But since `isBig 7` is `True`, it will stop and return `True`:

```
ghci> anyBig (1 : 7 : repeat 1)
True
```

Comment: Ok, I think between you and the comment I have a clearer picture now. Is there a way to see the evaluation steps with `ghci` or with some debugging tools? I think this would be really useful.

Comment: @MannyC: you have `ghc-vis` which shows how the objects are manipulated http://felsin9.de/nnis/ghc-vis/

Comment: @MannyC: you can also use `:print variable` to see how far it got evaluated (yet). So if you store the `x = map isBig [7,1,2,1]` somewhere, run `or x` and then `:print x`, you will see that it is not fully evaluated.